# Using namespaces in C# using mono

Tags: c#, mono, namespaces

I am trying to run a C# program in linux using mono gmcs compiler. I need to include a namespace Microsoft.Boogie. I have the source code for the C# package which defines Boogie namespace. But when I try to use

```
using Microsoft.Boogie;
```

the compiler (gmcs) complains that

```
boogieTrace.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Boogie' does not 
exist in the namespace `Microsoft'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Does anyone know how to include custom namespaces in a C# program?

Comment: Where is that namespace defined?  It has to exist in the project somewhere, either in source code or in a reference.

Comment: You say you've got the source code for the package - have you *built* that source code, and then added a reference to the resulting assembly?

Comment: How do I add a reference to the assembly?

Comment: Using the `-r` compiler option.